# Man who can't transform back, because he's certain he was dying when he last transformed

Tags: story-identification, novel, super-hero

In a recent online discussion, we were talking about superheroes who could transform into a body with a fixed age (it started with discussing Billy Batson and Captain Marvel Jr, cases where the superheroic form was a fixed older, and fixed younger, age) and I recalled having read a bit of fiction where one of the characters, male, had a heroic form, which they never transformed out of, and it was revealed later in the story that part of the reason was that the last time they transformed, they were experiencing a searing pain across their chest, and they're fairly certain they were having a fatal heart attack, I think in part due to his age. Unfortunately, I can't actually recall the work in question. I am 95% certain it was a book, although I suppose it could have been a short story. I don't remember for certain whether the heroic form was actually a fixed age, or just in better shape such that they could only survive by staying transformed. I also don't recall what wound up happening to them, although part of my brain wants to say that part of the climax of the story was them letting go of the transformation, and letting themselves finally die.

I also have this niggling bit in my brain where they might have been in a post-apocalyptic society, further explaining why the man couldn't be helped with his condition, and why it was further important for him to be able to exert his special abilities.

Comment: Has similarities with "Hulk - The End" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk:_The_End), although that was merely post apocalyptic with no society left.

Comment: I'm reminded of what happens to [Jason Blood](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jason_Blood_(New_Earth)#Breaking_the_Bond) after separation from Etrigan.